# Run as another user with PyCharm remote interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have PyCharm set up with a remote interpreter to a CentOS machine. After setting up the remote interpreter, everything works fine. However, there are some python scripts that I need to run with a user that is not me, what I would do, is:

```
sudo -u another-user python my_script.py
```

Is there a way that I can add the `sudo -u another-user` when PyCharm runs all scripts on the remote interpreter? I really don't care if it asks me for the sudo password every time.